# JavaScript SetInterval/setTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, css, animation, dom

Basically, I need to completely reload/reinitialize the banner animations after 14 seconds, yet after just 13 seconds - I want to shut down some of them (easing), so everything can stop and prepare itself before another run.

I have tried the following code with no luck:

```
banner.init();

setInterval(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        banner.wheel(); // Shuts down the wheel with 1s easing
        banner.deinitialize(); // Sets all animations to initial stage
    }, 13000);
    banner.wheel(true); // Does turn the spinning wheel back on
    banner.init(); // Puts all reinitialized animations back in motion
}, 14000);
```

I cannot use anything other than pure JS. Have you got any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: What means no luck?  What is happening? Are there any error or misbehaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout is going to fire 13s after the 14s interval. You need to invert them:

```
setInterval(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        banner.wheel(true); // Does turn the spinning wheel back on
        banner.init(); // Puts all reinitialized animations back in motion
    }, 1000);
    banner.wheel(); // Shuts down the wheel with 1s easing
    banner.deinitialize(); // Sets all animations to initial stage
}, 13000);
```

This will fire the interval after 13s which will start the easing, then after another 1s will reinitialize the other banners.

Comment: What if I wanted to do something in the halfway of this interval? Like for instance shut the wheel halfway?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Mock banner object for testing
var banner = {
  init: function(){console.log('banner.init')},
  wheel: function(on){console.log('Wheel', on)},
  deinitialize: function(){console.log('banner.deinitialize')},
}

banner.init();

function allOn() {
  banner.wheel(true); // Does turn the spinning wheel back on
  banner.init(); // Puts all reinitialized animations back in motion
}
function spinDown(){
  banner.wheel(); // Shuts down the wheel with 1s easing
  banner.deinitialize(); // Sets all animations to initial stage
}
function animateBanner(){
  allOn()
  setTimeout(spinDown, 13000);
}

setInterval(animateBanner, 14000);
```